# Office developer support email address dxipfb@microsoft.com not working

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I browsed to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/support to report a bug with the site.  On that page, I found dxipfb@microsoft.com for reporting site bugs I found.  I tried sending email to this address.  However the email was bounced back.  Below is the error I got.

The group dxipfb only accepts messages from people in its organization or on its allowed senders list, and your email address isn't on the list.

Could you please fix it!
Thanks,
-co

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a microsoft support request, not a programming problem.

Comment: I understand your frustration @piet.t. I really ran out of options.  If only I was able to get any help from microsoft support.  None of the options on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/support works and link to here from that page is the last resort I was trying. :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback, I identified the route cause and applied a fix. This problem should be resolved in the next hour or so. Please ping me if you still see issues

Thanks
Keith

Comment: Thank you very much! The issue seems resolved. I resent my email and it is not bounced back this time :)

Comment: Could you please also add the correct point of contact which should be used to address These issues? Thank you!

Comment: You can use the support alias to report bugs on the website specifically where you found the issue. Other issues not related to the website will most likely not be answered as its the wrong channel - the eng team behind it only looks after the web properties whete that suppprt page lives. For anything else you can use this forum or other support routes with regard to getting help on your issue. Hope that helps

Comment: "For anything else you can use this forum..." Wrong! This Q&A site is strictly limited to programming questions and it is not a forum....